# Photo extension storyboard with Autolayout error

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-extension

Recently i am writing an photo extension for my app.

However, i find the extension's storyboard cannot figure out the frame for each view with AutoLayout correctly.

For example I set this in the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

However when i run the simulator it shows:
[image]

Also, when i check the frame for my customized view in `didMoveToWindow()`, it also shows the incorrect frame :

> (66.0, 512.0, 468.0, 30.0)

Actually, the customized slider works fine in my app's storyboard.

What's wrong with me?

*Ps: the slider here is a customized `UIView` not a `UISlider`*

---

**Edit:**

By replacing the class to UIView (with color) on storyboard, i am now sure it is not the problem of Autolayout constraints because everything works fine.

Then i found the problem is in the process that I init this customized UIView, I set up my knobs and bar in the method `didMoveToWindow()`, whose frames depend on the View's frame. When i print the frame of the View at the top of `didMoveToWindow()`, the frame is not correct at all.

So I cannot get the correct frame of a UIView in its `didMoveToWindow()` method when using Autolayout?

But that works fine in my original app. So i am confused.

**Edit2**

I use a delay function to re-check its frame after 5 seconds :

```
func delay(#seconds: Double, completion:()->()) {
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64( Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds ))
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    completion()
    }
}
override func didMoveToWindow() {
    delay(seconds: 5, {
        println(self.frame)
    })
}
```

5 seconds later, the frame is correct! So, when the method is called, constraints are not applied yet. So now what i need to do is to get call-back in UIView when its superView's ViewController finish `ViewDidLoad`.

**Edit3**

I find the answer. I should set up subView's frame in UIView's `layoutSubviews()` method. In that case i can get the right frame when using Autolayout.

Actually, after the UIView's constraints are applied, it will call its `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: wrong constraints.....

Comment: leading space constraints of the first slider....

Comment: 512 and 468? thats what you need to fix it!

Comment: @Bhavin the slider here is a customized UIView not a UISlider

Answer (score 1):

Read this => it's helps you alot :)

[learn-to-love-auto-layout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/)
**OR**
 if you want to [LOVE AUTO LAYOUT… PROGRAMMATICALLY](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)
[image: 1 i/p image]
[image: 2 i/p image]
[image: out put image]

Comment: the slider here is a customized UIView not a UISlider

Comment: hmm.. I know that replace it by your `UIView`. This is just for reference.. :)

Comment: Did you try this constraints? Please  try.. this might helps you :)

Comment: Since mine is UIView, so i have to give it a height constant, except it, i think we bacially have the same set of layout constraints

Comment: Thanks body, I think i find the problem now, see my edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving trailing and leading space, apply this simple constraints.

1. Make your height constant (If you want to!)
2. Put UIView in center of the container
3. Give "Horizontal Center in Container" constraint
4. Apply appropriate "top space" and "bottom space"

That's it! You're done.